# using svgz in html server

Tags: svg, svgz

I use chrome to visualize a svg file which I put on a server, that works fine. Here's the dead simple html for it:

```
<a href="test.svg">svg</a>
```

However, when I try to use svgz instead, it doesn't work. Here's the code I use:

```
<a href="test.svgz">svgz</a>
```

Here the error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>   error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Looks to me that the browser doesn't decompress the file first.
Any idea how can I make this (much smaller) svgz file to display nicely on my browser?

Answer (score 3):

I had to add a .htaccess in the web folder root with the following content:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
AddEncoding x-gzip .svgz
```

From those 2 links [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/svg-developers@yahoogroups.com/msg07336.html) and [here](http://www.codedread.com/SVGKS_2b.php)

Comment: Actually that stopped working (same error message. I don't understand what's going on...)

Comment: Many, many thanks. This, in conjunction with enabling mod_filter (and of course deflate_module and the corresponding `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml`) was the only think that worked after digging across the entire internet.

Answer (score 1):

The info on this page solve my problem with IIS
http://forums.iis.net/t/1175276.aspx/1

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Rewrite SVGZ header" preCondition="IsSVGZ" stopProcessing="true">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Encoding" pattern=".*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="gzip" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="IsSVGZ">
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="\.svgz$" />
            </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's fixed in build 13536 and greater ⟨http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9737⟩ so I guess you just have to upgrade the browser?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it turned out to be something else

Comment: What was the something else? I'm having the same issue. How did you fix it?